# Pyspark groupBy: Get minimum value for column but retrieve value from different column of same row

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to group my data in PySpark - I have data from cars travelling around a track.

I want to group on race id, car, driver etc - but for each group I want to take the first and last recorded times - which I have done below.
I also want to take the tyre pressure from the first recorded row. I have tried to do the below but I'm getting the error:

"...due to data type mismatch: WHEN expressions in CaseWhen should all be boolean type"

Will be grateful for any suggestions!

Thanks

**Raw data:**

```
+---------+-----------+----------+--------+---------------+---------------+
| race_id | car_type  | car_make | driver | time_recorded | tyre_pressure |
+---------+-----------+----------+--------+---------------+---------------+
| 1       | manual    | ford     | juan   | 09:32         | 35            |
+---------+-----------+----------+--------+---------------+---------------+
| 1       | manual    | ford     | juan   | 09:45         | 34            |
+---------+-----------+----------+--------+---------------+---------------+
| 1       | manual    | ford     | juan   | 09:53         | 33            |
+---------+-----------+----------+--------+---------------+---------------+
| 1       | automatic | mazda    | bob    | 09:32         | 31            |
+---------+-----------+----------+--------+---------------+---------------+
| 1       | automatic | mazda    | bob    | 09:43         | 30            |
+---------+-----------+----------+--------+---------------+---------------+
| 2       | automatic | merc     | linda  | 10:11         | 33            |
+---------+-----------+----------+--------+---------------+---------------+
| 2       | automatic | merc     | linda  | 10:18         | 32            |
+---------+-----------+----------+--------+---------------+---------------+
| 2       | automatic | merc     | linda  | 10:27         | 32            |
+---------+-----------+----------+--------+---------------+---------------+
```

**Goal:**

```
+---------+-----------+----------+--------+------------+----------+---------------------+
| race_id | car_type  | car_make | driver | start_time | end_time | start_tyre_pressure |
+---------+-----------+----------+--------+------------+----------+---------------------+
| 1       | manual    | ford     | juan   | 09:32      | 09:53    | 35                  |
+---------+-----------+----------+--------+------------+----------+---------------------+
| 1       | automatic | mazda    | bob    | 09:32      | 09:43    | 31                  |
+---------+-----------+----------+--------+------------+----------+---------------------+
| 2       | automatic | merc     | linda  | 10:11      | 10:27    | 33                  |
+---------+-----------+----------+--------+------------+----------+---------------------+
```

**Code:**

```
EVENTS_GROUPED = EVENTS \
    .groupBy(['race_id', 'car_type', 'car_make', 'driver']) \
        .agg(
            f.min(f.col('time_recorded')).alias('start_time'),
            f.max(f.col('time_recorded')).alias('end_time'),
            f.when(f.min(f.col('time_recorded')), f.col('tyre_pressure')).alias('start_tyre_pressure'),
        )
```

Comment: Can you please share your data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a window function, then use a groupby. The idea is to create the `first_tyre_pressure` column before doing the groupby. To create this column we need the window function.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('race_id', 'car_type', 'car_make', 'driver').orderBy('time_recorded')

df.withColumn('start_tyre_pressure', F.first('tyre_pressure').over(w).alias('start_tyre_pressure'))\
             .groupby('race_id', 'car_type', 'car_make', 'driver', 'start_tyre_pressure')\
             .agg(F.min('time_recorded').alias('start_time'),
                  F.max('time_recorded').alias('end_time')).show()
```

Output

```
+-------+---------+--------+------+-------------------+----------+--------+
|race_id| car_type|car_make|driver|start_tyre_pressure|start_time|end_time|
+-------+---------+--------+------+-------------------+----------+--------+
|      1|automatic|   mazda|   bob|                 31|     09:32|   09:43|
|      2|automatic|    merc| linda|                 33|     10:11|   10:27|
|      1|   manual|    ford|  juan|                 35|     09:32|   09:53|
+-------+---------+--------+------+-------------------+----------+--------+
```